# Trying to add a default image/ if image = null reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to get a default image to show not sure where I'm going wrong I thought that adding an if statement to display if its null would work (I have added where I thought it went but its not working)  just not sure where I'm going wrong with it. I'm wondering if I am putting it n the wrong place or something or if I have to change my undeclared states.

```
 class RandomFilm extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      title: '',
      date:'',
      overview: '',
      poster: '',
      vote: ''
    }
    this.getFilm=this.getFilm.bind(this);
  }

 movieID(){
  var maxNumber = 284054;
  var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random()* maxNumber )+1);
  return randomNumber
}
getImgUrl (image) {
  return 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/' + image;

  if(image !== "null"{
    $('img').att('src', image);
  })
}

  getFilm = () => {
    const newMovieID = this.movieID()
    const url = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${newMovieID}?api_key=${apikey}`
    axios.get(url)
    .then(data => {
      let res = data.data;
      console.log(res);
      this.setState({
        title: res.title,
        date: res.release_date,
        overview: res.overview,
        poster: res.poster_path,
        vote: res.vote_average

      })
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('error')
    })
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.poster);
    return (
      <div >
      <h1 className="tagline"> Lets see what you got</h1>

      <div className="main">

        <div className="poster"name="poster_path">
        <img  className=" image" src={this.getImgUrl(this.state.poster)} alt="picture" />
        </div>
      <div className="content">
        <h1 name="title">{this.state.title}</h1>
        <hr/>
      <p name="date">Release date:{this.state.date}</p>
      <p name="overview">Description:{this.state.overview}</p>
        <p name="vote_average">Vote:{this.state.vote}</p>
      </div>

      </div>
      <div className="btn-area">
      <button className="btn" onClick={this.getFilm}>Get Movie</button>
      </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default RandomFilm;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery to set the image source for the default. Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sygn/69z2wepo/119780/)

```
getImgUrl (image) { 
    if (image === null) { 
        return '/noimage.jpeg';
    }
     return 'http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/'; + image; 
}
```

Note: Set your initial poster value also to null.

```
this.state = {
      title: '',
      date:'',
      overview: '',
      poster: null,
      vote: ''
    }
```

Comment: Ive done this and nothing changes any ideas why ?

getImgUrl (image) {
  if (image === 'null') {
    return './noimage.jpeg';
  }
  return 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/' + image;

}

Comment: does your api return `null` or a stringified `'null'`?  `null` is different from `'null'`

Comment: poster_path: null
 is whats in the console

Comment: whats the public path to your noimage.jpeg?

Comment: noimage.jpeg is in the same folder as my randomFilm.js

Comment: do you have bundle which handles file imports(webpack)? if not try adding the public path of the image ex. `/public/my_img.png`

Comment: I have gulp, sorry if I sound really stupid not been doing this long and first big project all my other pictures work fine like my logo 

can I try import it at the top of the page and use {NoImage} in anyway ?

Comment: add your default image to your statics folder, no need to import it in react, in the src put the public path inside `/your/public/path`

Comment: so the link to it should look something like './src/components/pages/randomfilm/randomFilm' ?

if not what is the public path

Comment: under public path i mean the path to the image on the server(either localhost or your remote)

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to use jquery, you can set a `imageIsNull: true` and `image: ""` properties in your state in your constructor, then in your `getURL` function do:

```
  if(image !== "null"){
    this.setState({image, imageIsNull : false})
  })
```

Then use conditional rendering in `render()` like this:

```
{ if(!this.state.imageIsNull) { return(<img src={this.state.image}>) }
```